# Automatically login people on specific websites using Electron

Tags: javascript, cookies, authentication, google-chrome-extension, electron

I created a small application using Electron ( http://electron.atom.io ). I want to add a feature that automatically logs in people on specific websites, on **any type of browser**.

The way I though of this is if Electron automatically completes the username and password fields of the website OR it sends an ajax request using the website's window context ( inject himself somehow into the content ).

I know that is possible to achieve this if I create extensions for each browser but it will take too long.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured that I will use the following approach:

I've found where most browsers keep their cookies, so I will upload the cookies there. When the user accesses the browser, it will be automatically logged in.

Comment: Hey @Alexandru, did you manage to succeed using electron? Can you share more details ? Tks

Answer (score 0):

The problem you will face is all browsers are set to prevent what is known as cross-site scripting. Basically I can create a frame inside a page or within the same domain and manipulate the dom of this externally sourced frame but I can not do this with a source from another domain.

So scripting across to fill and submit the form won't work which leaves you to trying to send a HTTP GET or POST through AJAX. Which the problem we reach here is that the site you are logging into is likely to check the referring URL to ensure the referrer is from it's own domain. While technically jquery has a method of setting the referrer header, unfortunately the browser resets this header in any cross site transactions for security purposes.

So basically there is no way to accomplish this reliably from a browser side script as the browsers are very restrictive when it comes to security measures. You will be able to login via AJAX to any sites that don't check their referrer header, but other than that you would need an arrangement with the websites your logging into, or use a more unrestricted platform that will allow you to manipulate the DOM cross site or spoof the Referrer Headers.

Comment: I never said anything about cross-site scripting. By injecting <script> tag inside of any browser window, I can submit Ajax requests from the same domain. So there is no need for Header spoofing. The question is: can I edit the contents of another browser window using Electron ?